# How to show page before executing OnGet?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page that shows a 'Please wait' box and the `OnGet` method does some stuff that might take a few seconds and ends with a `LocalRedirect`.

The razor code:

```
@page

@inject IStringLocalizer<Startup> localizer

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                <div class="help-block text-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border" role="status" />
                </div>
                <p class="login-box-msg">@localizer["PleaseWait"]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    //Do some stuff that takes a few seconds...

    return LocalRedirect("/Dashboard");
}
```

Everything is working apart from the page first being shown and then executing the code.

Is it possible to first render the page (so that the users can see that something is happening) and then execute the code in the `OnGet`?

Comment: It depneds on the code pattern you have now, could you please share you code snippet so that it can be investigated. In addition, what you are expecting also add that note as well.

Comment: So, rather redirecting directly to here ` return LocalRedirect("/Dashboard");` you would like to hold the user few second before right? For instance: Loading/Please wait...we are redirecting you... or something like am I understand correctly?

Comment: Hi, You should use **PartialViews** and **Ajax** (example bellow): http://binaryintellect.net/articles/65cfe9cd-b98f-48b7-825d-31ae8008a91a.aspx

Comment: @TwiXter How does this help solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, Don't have time to create a full example. Check following links, this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217829/please-wait-page-in-asp-net-mvc https://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/displaying-a-wait-message-on-an-mvc-page Of course i don't know which pattern you are using or even if it's aspNet, aspNet.core... this could help other persons that can answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your long `async` routines from `OnGet` to a number of [named handler methods](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods). Allow the page to render a "please wait" message and use client-side code (jQuery AJAX or plain Fetch) to call the named handlers. Keep track of when they complete and when all have completed, redirect to the other page.

Here's an example where the `OnGet` simply renders the page (can include a "please wait" message"), and a number of named handlers simulate routines of varying length:

```
public void OnGet()
{
}
public async Task OnGetTwoSeconds()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
public async Task OnGetThreeSeconds()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
public async Task OnGetFiveSeconds()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

The following script goes in the Razor page itself. It consists of three variables for tracking task completion and a method that redirects to the home page when all three have completed. Each of the named handlers is called by the code and sets its tracking variable to true on completion as well as calling the `redirect` function:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        let twosecondsdon = false;
        let threesecondsdone = false;
        let fivesecondsdone = false;
        function redirect(){
            if (twosecondsdone && threesecondsdone && fivesecondsdone) {
                location.href = '/';
            }
        }
        fetch('?handler=TwoSeconds').then(() => {
            twosecondsdone = true;
            redirect();
        })
        fetch('?handler=ThreeSeconds').then(() => {
            threesecondsdone = true;
            redirect();
        })
        fetch('?handler=FiveSeconds').then(()=>{
            fivesecondsdone = true;
            redirect();
        })
    </script>
}
```

When all three complete, the `redirect` function does its thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to first render the page (so that the users can see
> that something is happening) and then execute the code in the OnGet?

Yes you can do that. Currently, I am showing you the delay counter where you can replace your page. Please follow the steps below:

**HTML:**

**Script:**

```cs
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            var counter = 5;
            (function countDown() {
                if (counter-- > 0) {
                    $('#timer').text("Please wait... we are redirecting you to register page..." + counter + ' s');
                    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "https://localhost:44361/userlog/ViewCalculateAge";// Here put your controller URL where you would like to redirect
                }
            })();


        });
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]